# How to order dates in descending order when there are multiple years in data set

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution, google-query-language

I have an Integromat app pulling weather data with date-time and adding them to my sheet and then I use that data to make some graphs.

The sheet in question can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QEw5CBno6j-2vIXDOFO7TqhA9m-rzNWsyVziw9SoQIs/edit?usp=sharing). The weather data is the *Data* sheet

The issues are in GraphData!A18, GraphData!A31, and GraphData!A130. If I use

`=SORT(QUERY(Data!A:D,"order by A desc limit 366"),1,1)`

in GraphData!A130, it excludes data from the year 2022 as my date-time is in the format `12.31.2021 01:36`. I can't change how Integromat outputs data. I tried to use **Format>Number>Custom date and time** but it didn't change anything. So, how do I go about changing the formula to also include 2022 data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your dates are not valid dates but text strings. to convert them try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({Data!A:D, SUBSTITUTE(Data!A:A, ".", "/")*1}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 order by Col5 desc", 1))
```

[image]